# Link that refers to a menu item with dynamically generated URL

Tags: menus, links

I have a menu item that always links to the latest post from a specific category. The link is generated dynamically. So every time I create a new post, the menu item URL changes.

I need a CTA Button that links to this menu item, no matter what the URL is.
Something like this:
`<a href="link to menu item 'new-deals'">New Deals</a>`

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wp_get_recent_posts function in your own custom function.

Something like this should work:

```
function get_recent_post_link(){
    // Restrict to latest post
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
    // Get the post
    $latest_post = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $latest_post as $the_post ){
        return get_permalink($the_post["ID"]);
    }
}
```

You can the call the function in your anchor:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_recent_post_link(); ?>">Latest</a>
```

Note, I have not tested this, please use as a guideline.